# Python/CSV - File not found error

Tags: python, csv

A basic question but I've got a file, say file.csv, in the directory, `C:/Users/User/Desktop/Other/DataAnalysis/CurrentData/file.csv`, and so I've written,

`df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Other/DataAnalysis/CurrentData/file.csv")`

and I get an error -

```
> FileNotFoundError: File
> b'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Other/DataAnalysis/CurrentData/file.csv' does not exist
```

I've tried

`df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")`

As the file.csv is in the exact same folder as my python script, and I still get the same error. I'm not sure what I've done wrong. I've checked the python API and I've tried reversing the brackets (so using \\ instead of /), and still doesn't work. 
Thank you.

Comment: df = d.read_csv("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Other/DataAnalysis/CurrentData/file.csv")  what is d here i guess you are referring to pandas as pd am I right?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice. Yes, it's suppose to be pd.read_csv. Let me edit that. Also, I do have "import pandas as pd ".

Comment: Is there a chance that your file full name is `file.csv.csv` and you hide extensions in your file system? @JamesWu

Comment: Hi Yoram, you're correct. It appears that I did have extensions hidden! Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
with open(my_file, 'r') as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        print(line)
```

That way you can check if Python can open the file at all.

Comment: Hi Uwain, I've used your code just then and it works perfectly. Based on Yoram's suggestion, I needed to add another .csv, but your code helps to see if it opens! I've got bits of code after and so it'll save me heaps of time! Cheers

Comment: Glad to help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check the extension it might be `.csv.txt` or `.csv.csv`

Answer (score 0):

> Window users

use forward slash:

```
import pandas as pd
df_swing = pd.read_csv('D:/anaconda/envs/data/EDA/2008_all_states.csv')
```

Example shown above is of absolute path. It's complete path from the base of your file system to the file that you want to load, e.g. c:/Documents/Shane/data/test_file.csv. Absolute paths will start with a drive specifier (c:/ or d:/ in Windows, or ‘/’ in Mac or Linux)